# Strange Default Browser Issue

Tags: windows-7, windows, browser

I have set my default browser to "firefox".  However, I have one application that insists on opening Opera instead of the default browser no matter what I do.

I have contacted the vendor concerning the application and they say that the application opens the standard default browser and that they are doing the standard thing.

I have checked my browser settings and they do confirm that the default browser is firefox.

Is there some other registry setting that is causing this application to open a different browser other than my default?

I am running Windows 7 patched to current.

Comment: It the WinAntiRamsom program from winpatrol.com.....However, I have seen this particular situation happen in a couple of other applications but I cannot recall now.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, your app vendor is using some old/obsolete way to detect the default browser (such as checking HKLM before HKCU), which returns the wrong result in Windows 7.

Detecting the `standard default browser` is not as straightforward as it may sound, and the ways to do it correctly have changed over time between different versions of Windows. Lookup [How Does Your Browser Know that It’s Not The Default?](https://newoldthing.wordpress.com/2007/03/23/how-does-your-browsers-know-that-its-not-the-default-browser/) for more details than is room to copy here.

While the linked article gives a list of registry keys to look at, the article itself dates back to Windows Vista so it's rather outdated nowadays. The ultimate recourse would be to run [Process Monitor](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processmonitor.aspx) and look for registry reads from the app in question just before Opera is launched.